# SQL Replace and Update a Datetime string "before a certain date"

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, replace

I have a data field `Date` in the format of `yyyyMMdd` string (varchar). How do I replace everything before a certain date, say 20180201, to certain month, say March 2018!? Only the year and the month are changed, keep the day.

Example: A string **20160913** will be changed to **20180313**, but **20180224** will be kept as it was, because it was after **20180201**.

Comment: Real `date` columns have no "format". What data type is that column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name "_in the format of yyyyMMdd string_" -> string/varchar/char

Comment: Sorry... it's SQL Server...

Comment: don't store your dates as strings

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Well... I agree with you! But that's not the point, is it!? There are cases where you have no control of the design of the database, eg. maintaining somebody else's database! So, how should I do if the date was "stocked" as a string!? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It should be "stuck"! Not "stocked"!!! What the heck is that!?!?!? >"<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert that string to a date to search for the greater than a date, and use substring to extract the day part to build the new date string.

```
declare @NewYear varchar(4) = '2018'
declare @NewMonth varchar(2) = '03'
declare @PivotDate date = '2018-02-01'

update myTable set MyField = @NewYear + @NewMonth + substring(MyField, 6, 2)
where convert(date, MyField, 112) > @PivotDate
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing this as:

```
declare @NewYear varchar(4) = '2018';
declare @NewMonth varchar(2) = '03';
declare @PivotDate date = '2018-02-01';

update myTable
    set MyField = @NewYear + @NewMonth + right(MyField, 2)
where myfield < convert(varchar(255), @PivotDate, 112);
```

The important part of this solution is the `where` clause.  In particular, there is no function call on `myfield` which allows an index to be used.  An expression that allows an index is called *sargable*.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to doing this, because if @NewMonth < February, then it can be a problem.

```
declare @NewYear varchar(4) = '2018'
declare @NewMonth varchar(2) = '02'
declare @PivotDate date = '2018-02-01'

update myTable set MyField = DATEADD(day,(right(MyField, 2)-1),cast((@NewYear + @NewMonth + '01') as date))
where convert(date, MyField, 112) > @PivotDate
```

Thank You!