# Update a column of multiple selected rows of datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

For example  have database and it displays in my datagridview like this:

```
Name  | Date    | Position     | 
------+---------+--------------+
Ben   | April   | CEO          |
Ren   | May     | COO          |
Ken   | August  | Assistant    |
```

This are my table attributes

```
Name = `varchar`
Date = `datetime`
Position = `varchar`
```

I want to Update my "Date" column with all of the months into December or to any month I choose in my datetimepicker tool whenever I click my update button.

here is my code that I have in my Update Button:

```
con.Open();  

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter ("Update TableSample set Date = 
'"+textboxDateTimePicker.Text+"', Position = '"+textboxPosition.Text+"' 
where Name = '"+texboxName.text+"' ", con);`

sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: Let me get this straight... you want to update the `Date` in the database using SQL commands!?

Comment: Please check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252225/sql-replace-and-update-a-datetime-string-before-a-certain-date)

Comment: That is the only method I know for I am new in programming, any help, suggestions that can teach me is very much appreciated.

Comment: So you're trying to learn "other" methods to do the same job!? In my opinion... a good method only need one!!! As for the other things that will improve your programming skill... the only suggestion I could give you is keep writing it "a lot"!!! The more you programming... the better you'll become!!! There is NO other way around it!!!

Comment: thanks, I am, that is why I am asking for help in a certain part which I have posted, I did not  ask on  how to improve my programming as a whole. :D

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)